# image map when hover change another DIV content

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I have the below code, my question is how to do an image map (circle mapping) when hover that can change another DIV content?

here is an example, this image has 5 circles, when I mouse over each one, I want to display different text on the result DIV.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if($("#planet").find(".circle1:hover").length){
    $('#result').html('Hoving purple');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src ="http://placehold.it/400x400" width="400" height="400" alt="Planets"
     usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap" id="planet">
  <area shape="circle" coords="107,93,60" class="circle1" alt="purple" title="purple">
  <area shape="circle" coords="288,73,60" class="circle2" alt="red" title="red">
  <area shape="circle" coords="86,272,60" class="circle3" alt="orange" title="orange">
  <area shape="circle" coords="368,222,60" class="circle4" alt="green" title="green">
  <area shape="circle" coords="240,348,60" class="circle5" alt="blue" title="blue">
</map>

<div id="result">not hover</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx1q8rfu/

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found out that there is a easy hover function

```
$(document).ready(function () {



$(".circle1").hover(function(){
      $('#result').html('This is purple');


   });

$(".circle2").hover(function(){
      $('#result').html('This is red');


   });

$(".circle3").hover(function(){
      $('#result').html('This is orange');


   });
$(".circle4").hover(function(){
      $('#result').html('This is green');


   });
$(".circle5").hover(function(){
      $('#result').html('This is blue');


   });







});
```